# Setting file modification time before the year 1900

Tags: windows, perl, filesystems

I'm in the process of creating a problematic data set and I'm looking to set the year of the modification times of files to <1900. I know that [Time::Local](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html) uses an offset from 1900. I was wondering if there was any way around using this offset to create files whose modification times occur before the year 1900. (Windows Enviroment btw.)

This is the code I've been using so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::stat; 
use Time::localtime;
use Time::Local;

my $file = "test.txt";      
my $when = timelocal(0,0,10,25,6,1899);

#current mod time of the file
my $datetime_string = ctime(stat($file)->mtime);
print $datetime_string,"\n";

#change the mod time of the file
utime $when, $when, $file;

#new mod time
$datetime_string = ctime(stat($file)->mtime);
print $datetime_string,"\n";
```

**Edit**: In regards to @ikegami 's comment, I did start to look into `Win32::API`. Specifically `Win32API::File::Time`. This is the code that I have so far for that:

```
use Win32API::File::Time qw{:win};
$filename="AnnotationTest.java";
($atime, $mtime, $ctime) = GetFileTime ($filename);
print $mtime,"\n";
SetFileTime ($filename, $atime, $mtime, $ctime);
($atime, $mtime, $ctime) = GetFileTime ($filename);
print $mtime,"\n";
```

With this code I'm not 100% sure what the format of the modification time is.

Comment: Does not [the page you linked](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html#Year-Value-Interpretation) provides an answer? `Years greater than 999 are interpreted as being the actual year, rather than the offset from 1900. Thus, 1964 would indicate the year Martin Luther King won the Nobel prize, not the year 3864.`. However, this still has the problem of setting year prior to 1000.

Comment: Just added a code block. The way I'm using it above, specifying the year as 1899 does not set it to 1899. It just seems to keep it whatever year it was at before I attempt the change.

Comment: XY problem: why do you want to set modification times to paradoxical values? you should store this data in another way.

Comment: As I said in the question, "I'm in the process of creating a problematic data set". I'm going to use this "problematic data set" for testing an application.

Comment: `stat` returns timestamps in the unix epoch format, which is a positive number of seconds since Jan 1st, 1970. It wouldn't be able to handle older timestamps. You might have to use a Windows system call. Win32::API could help to do that.

Comment: @ikegami I did begin to look into `Win32API`, I added an additional code block with what I have so far in regards to `Win32API`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that utime supports going that far back. If it's a signed 32-bit offset from 1970 then that only gets you to 1901 afaict. Is there a cut-off around -(2**31)?

Comment: While FAT's epoch is 1980, NTFS's epoch is apparently 1601!! wikipedia: "File times are 64-bit numbers counting 100-nanosecond intervals (ten million per second) since 1601"

Comment: @ikegami - I remembered reading that NTFS went a long way back. Didn't know it was that far! That doesn't necessarily mean utime will though - presumably it's a unix port.